Error: framesToPop”:1, “name”:“Invariant Violation”
I got an error message in the attached code section when the apollo client instance is made in Node.js, typeScript, firebase functions backend environment.
The error message says {“message”:{“framesToPop”:1,“name”:“Invariant Violation”}}. Now, I use  "@apollo/client": "^3.7.10", "graphql": "^16.6.0", and engine is node 16v.
If you know something to fix this error, please teach it to me.
(https://i.sstatic.net/xYDfk.png)


expressApp.post("/sample", async (req: any, res: any) => {
  try {
    const data = req.body;
    console.log(`===req.body data is ${data}===`);

    // query to get proposal deta from $proposal_id
    const scoreQuery = gql`
      query Proposal($proposal_id: String!) {
        proposal(id: $proposal_id) {
          state
          scores
        }
      }
    `;

    /* @ERROR: Here, apollo client returns the below error.
      `{“message”:{“framesToPop”:1,“name”:“Invariant Violation”}}`;
    */
    const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
      uri: "https://hub.snapshot.org/graphql",
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });x
    
    ~~~



I'd like to search for voting data associated with a proposal id in snapshot
※snapshot is a voting service. https://snapshot.org/
